# Count distinct substring with Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

Is there a way for writing something like

SELECT COUNT ( DISTINCT ( SUBSTRING ("field", 5, 20) ) )
FROM MyTable;

through Hibernate Criteria?